# Connecting Node and DB-Sync

Tags: cardano-node, cardano-db-sync, cardano-graphql

I'm running Cardano Node and Cardano GraphQL on the same network/computer. This is how I started the node:

```
 cardano-node run \
   --topology /home/ubuntu/cardano/cardano-src/cardano-node/mainnet-topology.json \
   --database-path /home/ubuntu/cardano/cardano-src/cardano-node/data \
   --socket-path /home/ubuntu/cardano/cardano-src/cardano-node/data/node.socket \
   --host-addr xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx \
   --port 1911 \
   --config /home/ubuntu/cardano/cardano-src/cardano-node/mainnet-config.json
```

Wallet Start:

```
cardano-wallet serve \
      --port 1919 \
      --node-socket /home/ubuntu/cardano/cardano-src/cardano-node/data/node.socket \
      --mainnet \
      --database /home/ubuntu/cardano/cardano-src/cardano-node/data \
      --listen-address 0.0.0.0 \
```

Docker, GraphQL:

```
export NETWORK=mainnet &&\
docker pull inputoutput/cardano-graphql:6.2.0-${NETWORK} &&\
docker pull inputoutput/cardano-graphql-hasura:6.2.0 &&\
docker pull cardanosolutions/cardano-node-ogmios:v5.1.0-${NETWORK} &&\
RESTORE_SNAPSHOT=https://update-cardano-mainnet.iohk.io/cardano-db-sync/13/db-sync-snapshot-schema-13-block-7519843-x86_64.tgz \
docker-compose up -d &&\
docker-compose logs -f
```

How `db-sync` and `node` will communicate I did not pass any path of node data directory. I feel like Ogmios is pulling the same data as node did before and I'm storing the same data twice.

Answer (score 1):

The Ogmios image you're using has it's own node instance. From https://ogmios.dev/getting-started/docker :

> Ogmios docker images come in two flavours: cardano-node-ogmios and ogmios. The former is used to run a single container that bundles both a Cardano-node and an Ogmios server running side-by-side. It is likely the easiest way to get started. The latter is a standalone Ogmios server, and you’ll need to run that container in orchestration with a cardano-node; this is made relatively easy with Docker compose.